# One Way binding to an object in Windows 8

Tags: xaml, data-binding, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I have an Observable collection of objects that implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and this is bound to a ListView. I have created a DataTemplate for the ItemTemplate within which I have several elements bound to item properties with Converters to define what is displayed.
This is all working as expected and when an item property its related element is notified and updated via the converter.
What I need to do is bind an element in the datatemplate via a converter which is based on several of the items properties. I have managed to do this by binding element to the complete data item. However if any of the properties are updated this is not being notified to the element and the value is not being updated. How would I go about achieving this? I need someway of creating a notification that the item has changed when any of its properties have changed.

Comment: Have you considered using a MultiBinding?

Comment: @dowhilefor Not heard of that in win8 app development, I'll google/bing it.

Comment: @dowhilefor looks like MultiBinding is not currently available in Windows Metro apps.

Answer (score 0):

Take the logic from your converter and move it to a new property of the class and call PropertyChanged of the new property in the setters of the properties that it is dependent on.

If the class is sealed or otherwise unchangable, you could create a wrapper that does this.  Then add a converter to your ItemsSource binding that wraps the items in your collection.

Comment: Cheers, @kindasimple, this sounds like a potential work around but I will leave this open for a while to see if there are any other solutions. Didn't really want to add UI specific properties to my class but maybe I need to look at MVVM principles a bit more!